# What's your all-in-one web resource optimizer?

Tags: php, performance, optimization

I'm working with **SmartOptimizer**: minify js and css, use css data uris, add far expire headers and other features. (http://farhadi.ir/works/smartoptimizer) It works fine, but i don't know if exists a similiar application with similar or best tools (like Google Closure, CSScaffold,..)

If you're not sure witch is better, what's your favourite??

Thanks for reading, sorry for my english

Comment: Your English is fine by the way! Better than some people we get on here who have English as their main language!

Comment: Yeah, fine english buth still a subjective question and thus I voted to close it.

Comment: Yeah god forbid we can read opinions here on SO

Answer (score 0):

YSlow ( http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/ ) will tell you where you can optimize, at least, though it won't solve your problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

WEB optimizer(http://webo.name/) is a great thing. It can not only find issues, but also do some optimizing. However it isn't free for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

I have a JS and CSS compressor into my editor ([Coda.app](http://www.panic.com/coda/)), and I optimise images with [ImageOptim.app](http://imageoptim.pornel.net/). You just have to drag & drop the images, and the app does his job by choosing the best compression throwing it at multiple images libraries.
***Note***: MAC only